# Basis functions, functions spaces, inner products.

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis

I am currently doing a Physics degree and am in my first year. I have been introduced to the concept of Fourier series, and a prerequisite of that was an explanation of the inner product between functions and a mention of 'infinite dimensional spaces' of functions.

I can't see how a function would form an infinite dimensional space. I am aware that there would be an infinite of coordinates defining points in some region, but this would surely form an infinite set instead?

Also (and I guess as a corollary of me not understanding the above), how exactly do functions form a 'basis set' for other functions? And, what exactly does an inner product between functions represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A* function does not form a infinite dimensional space. However, a *collection* of functions may very well form such a space. A basic example would be the *space* of all polynomials.

When asking what it means to have a basis, that's just linear algebra, except that in infinite dimensions we tend to tweek the definition a bit.

So just to combine the two above points: The space of polynomials, call it $\mathcal{P}$, is infinite dimensional. What does that even mean? Well, it means that for any finite set of polynomials $p_1,...,p_n$, the linear span of $p_1,...,p_n$ is not equal to all of $\mathcal{P}$. How would I prove such a thing?

Well, since there are finitely many of them, there is a number $d$ such that the degree of each $p_i$ is at most $d$. Consider now the polynomial $p(x)=x^{d+1}$. I want to argue that $p$ does not lie in the linear span of $p_1,...,p_n$. Indeed, if it did, there would exist constants $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ such that $p(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ip_i(x)$ would be the zero-polynomial. But that can't be, since by elementary calculus, $\lim_{x\to \infty} p(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ip(x)=\infty$.

The conclusion is that $p$ does not lie in the linear span of $p_1,...,p_n$. Since these polynomials were arbitrary, $\mathcal{P}$ does not have a finite spanning set. Therefore, $\mathcal{P}$ is *not* finite dimensional.

Now, $\mathcal{P}$ admits the basis given by $p_i(x)=x^i$. That means that given a polynomial $q$, there exist unique constants $\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha_i=0$ for all but finitely many $i$ and $q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i p_i(x)$. This is perfectly analogous to classic linear algebra.

However, usually, in the infinite dimensional setting, we don't want the above condition that the $\alpha_i$ are only non-zero for finitely many $i$. It somehow clicks wrong with the theory. However, the good infinite dimensional notion of basis of a function space would still be that a set $\{f_i|i\in I\}$ forms a basis if for every $g$ in that space, there are unique $\alpha_i$ such that $g(x)=\sum_{i\in I} \alpha_i f_i(x)$.

Finally: What should the inner product represent? Well... I'm assuming we're talking about the inner product $\langle f, g\rangle=\int \bar{f}(x) g(x)\textrm{d}x$. One way to think about this is that it's *no* different from the usual inner product. You take the coordinate-wise product of the two vectors and then you "sum" them. Only, when you're in a continuous setting, summing is replaced by integration.

Indeed, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, you'd even get that if $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ and the distance between each $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ is small, then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{f}(x_i)g(x_i))(x_{i+1}-x_i) \approx \int_a^b \bar{f}(x) g(x)\textrm{d}x
$$
and the left-hand side is just a renormalised inner-product between the more classical vectors $(f(x_i))_{1\leq i\leq n}$ and $(g(x_i))_{1\leq i\leq n}$.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you! I am still not quite sure exactly what an inner product tells us or represents, however.

Comment: Well... what do you want it to represent? As a mathematician, I view it as a purely formal concept that is interesting because it has certain consequences *and* is easy to manipulate, making it amenable to analysis. Heuristically, it's *some* concept of angles on the space of functions and as I tried to indicate above, it's somehow the natural limit of normalised inner product of the finite-dimensional vectors (and hence also the angles between them) that one might extract from $f$ and $g$ by evaluating them at finitely many points.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question as being able to expand 'any' function in a Fourier series isn't trivial at all, in fact it has been one of the biggest problems in mathematics having had many of the greatest mathematicians working on it in the past.

It all builds upon the concept of a basis. If you've taken linear algebra, you will have seen things like the vectors $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\
0\end{pmatrix}$ and $e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ spanning all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, what that means is that we can get *any* element in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by taking linear combinations of $e_1$ and $e_2$, i.e. any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as
$$ae_1 + be_2$$ where $a, b$
are arbitrary constants. What makes this work is the fact that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are linearly independent.

Now what if we had a function instead of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$? It turns out that that the infinite set $$\{1/\sqrt2\, \sin(nx), \cos(nx) : n \in 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$$ is a linearly independent set that span all piece-wise continuous and periodic functions, so in the same way as before, we can express any such function as a linear combination of the basis vectors
$$f(x)\sim \frac{a_0}{\sqrt{2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos n x + b_n \sin nx)$$

where $a_0, a_n, b_n$ are constants determined by our function. This set is known as the *Fourier basis*.

As for what an inner product is, it is just an operation $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ we can equip our space with, in particular, it allows us to define angles between vectors through
\begin{align*}
    \cos{\theta} = \frac{\langle u, v\rangle}{\lvert u \rvert\lvert v \rvert}
\end{align*}
and thus we can now talk about orthogonality and orthogonal projections which can be helpful in determining the coefficients $a_n, b_n$ above.

Answer (score 0):

A function cannot possibly form an infinite dimensional space. But, say, the set of *all* continuous functions from $[0,2\pi]$ into $\Bbb R$ *is* an infinite dimensional space. The dimension is infinite because, for instance, it contains all functions of the form $x\mapsto x^n$, with $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. And you do nott need coordinates to work with elements from this vector space.

A natural inner product in this space is$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$